# dropdownlist dataSource add a created js string

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, kendo-ui, datasource

```
<script>
$("#dropdownlist").kendoDropDownList({
  dataSource: [
    { id:1, name: "Apples" },
    { id:2, name: "Oranges" }
  ],
  dataTextField: "name",
  dataValueField: "id"
});
var dropdownlist = $("#dropdownlist").data("kendoDropDownList");
 var jsonStr = "";
 for (var jx = 3; jx  < 21; jx++) 
 {
     jsonStr = '{ '
                  + 'id : '
                  + jx + 
                  ", "
                  + 'name : '
                  + '"blaaa_'+jx+ '"'
                  + ' }';
                  dropdownlist.dataSource.add(jsonStr);
                  // give me an "undefined" not a fruit (no errors in console)
                  // console.log(jsonStr);
}
dropdownlist.dataSource.add({ id : 21, name : "Strawbeery" });
// works
</script>
```

why can't i add a self created js string to my dataSource ? I although tried it with var Myresult = JSON.parse(jsonStr);

Answer (score 0):

You create your Datasource with local data, which is an array of objects (json format can only be used for binding to remote data).

If you want to add items in json format, you'll have to parse them first:

```
var parsedObject = JSON.parse(jsonObject);
dropdownlist.dataSource.add(parsedObject);
```

See working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/lhoeppner/82Cyt/

You could also extend the DataSource widget so it does this for you, however it's not really clear why you want to add json strings instead of JS objects in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are adding a string while `add` method expects a JSON object. So either use:

```
dropdownlist.dataSource.add(JSON.parse(jsonStr));
```

or much easier you build a JSON object as:

```
<script>
    $("#dropdownlist").kendoDropDownList({
        dataSource    : [
            { id: 1, name: "Apples" },
            { id: 2, name: "Oranges" }
        ],
        dataTextField : "name",
        dataValueField: "id"
    });
    var dropdownlist = $("#dropdownlist").data("kendoDropDownList");
    var jsonStr = "";
    for (var jx = 3; jx < 21; jx++) {
        json = {
            id  : jx,
            name: "blaaa" + jx
        };

        dropdownlist.dataSource.add(json);
    }
    dropdownlist.dataSource.add({ id: 21, name: "Strawbeery" });
</script>
```